# Why does Magento 2 composer.json require composer?

Tags: magento2, composer

Perhaps a stupid question but: Why does Magento 2 `composer.json` require Composer?

If you [look at the `composer.json`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/composer.json#L46) (either of the GitHub repo or the `composer.json` bundled with the downloaded archive from magento.com), you'll see something like:

```
"require": {
  ...
  "composer/composer": "@alpha"
  ...
}
```

or:

```
"require": {
  ...
  "composer/composer": "1.4.1"
  ...
}
```

So my question basically is: **Why would Magento (or any given Composer project) require composer itself?** I mean: You typically should already have installed composer on your system as a global library. So why include it then?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely because the Magento composer installer which is part of the Magento composer meta package needs a specific version and this way it has access to the code.